# RAID set up in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, raid, 18.04

I am trying to setup one of my servers with Ubuntu 18.04 server edition. When trying to do disk partitioning it does not allow me to choose Software RAID configuration (That open does not exist at all). How can I solve this.

Note: I tried with Ubuntu 16.04 and it works fine

Comment: What commands did you use as I have created it on a virtualbox instance of Ubuntu Bionic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're downloading the wrong version. Ubuntu 18.04 has a "live server" version which has a faster/easier, but less configurable installer.

You want to download the alternative installer instead: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/bionic/release/

Comment: This is a really interesting issue... I like the idea of a streamlined installer, but sometimes you need to configure things. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Going crazy with this problem where the gory details are on Usenet alt.os.linux at URL: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.os.linux/D7E7FQ1NLNk

*SUBJECT:*
Why doesn't Ubuntu 18.04 ask to install next to Windows 10 Pro single HDD as a dual boot?

Basically, Ubuntu 16.04 works fine but Ubuntu 18.04 installer fails every time:
 https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Checksum information
  **Name**: ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso
  **Size**: 1921843200 bytes (1832 MB)
  **SHA256**: A55353D837CBF7BC006CF49EEFF05AE5044E757498E30643A9199B9A25BC9A34

Some debugging commands that others will find useful and their output are:

```
blkid /dev/sd*

  /dev/sda: TYPE="promise_fasttrack_raid_member" <===== this is critical data!!!

  /dev/sda1: LABEL="Disk1" ... TYPE="ntfs" ... 

sudo fdisk -luS /dev/sd?

   Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
   ... 
   Disklabel type: dos
   Device = /dev/sda1
   Boot = * 
   Start = 2048
   End = 1871601663
   Sectors = 1871599616
   Size = 892.5G
   Id = 7 
   Type = HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

sudo apt install smartmontools
```

When it asks for a mail-server configuration, I selected:

```
   No configuration
```

Then I could run the smartctl command:

```
sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda
```

> > Power_On_Hours = 208 (Raw Value)

(The point is that it's a new HDD and I didn't get cheated with an old one!)

The net is that there is a huge bug in omission in the description for the Ubuntu 64-bit Desktop 18.04 installer which works DIFFERENTLY from the 64-bit Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 installer in the exact same machine under the exact same circumstances.

The Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop installer installs alongside Windows when the controller is RAID but the disks are not RAIDed; but the Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop installer not only barfs but it provides zero useful output under the exact same circumstances.

This bug is evident in the tutorials also in that they don't cover this situation in the least, so everyone is left to fumble willy nilly until they figure out, on their own, with no help from Ubuntu, about this bug.