# RAID support in Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop installer?

Tags: system-installation, raid, 18.04, mdadm

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop using a software RAID 1 configuration.  I don't see any RAID option in the installer.  I have found a [question about RAID support in the server installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029854/raid-set-up-in-ubuntu-18-04), but no info about the desktop installer.

How can I (as easy as possible) setup a Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop with RAID ?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html If what your installer does is not what it shows there please file a bugreport.

Comment: This guide is about the server installer, not the desktop.

Comment: And on the download page ( http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ ) "If you require LVM, RAID, multipath, network vlans, or network interface bonding during the installation; if you need to reuse existing partitions on your installation disk; or for support for other architectures besides AMD64/EM64T, see the alternative images location." you are told to use that one ;-)

Comment: But that one is going to install a server version without the graphical user interface.  I need a desktop install, with GUI, and with RAID support.

Comment: You do know you can install a desktop with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: Is it equivalent a desktop install to a server install followed by `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`?  Will the system end up with exactly the same packages installed?

Comment: Yes. 100%. A very long time ago Canonical dropped the server / desktop and created 1 base install (where there is a switch in the installer to have it install a desktop). With 18.04 though we got 2 installers (Ubiquity and sUbiquity where the "s" stands for server) That probably is where you problem stems from. The normal one is missing options.

Comment: @Óscar any success with your question? I'm trying to do the same and have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: @I.Newton yes, I did that, server install with RAID, followed by `apt install ubuntu-desktop` and it worked