# Error while installing Ubuntu server due to RAID configuration

Tags: server, system-installation, filesystem, raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server 18.04.2 AMD64 from a USB thumb drive. I get a problem when I define my disk partitions. I have an M.2 SSD, which I want to use as the boot and system disk, with a boot partition and a main partition mounted on /, and 2 Seagate Barracuda hard drives, which I want to use for a software RAID 1 array, mounted on /home. Here the filesystem setup:

[image: Ubuntu server Filesystem setup]

But I get the following answer on the following step:

[image: Error message on install]

What am I doing wrong with my RAID?

**Edit:**

I went back to that problem after a while, and I realized there is a log. So here some photos of the log of the operation. Sorry, but I can't retrieve the log file, as there is no OS installed on the machine:

[image: Error log extract - part 1]
[image: Error log extract - part 2]
[image: Error log extract - part 3]

Also, here the details of the steps I follow for that failed installation:

- Creating a boot partition and a partition for / on the SSD
- Creating a software RAID and adding both of my hard drives
- Creating a partition on the resulting RAID array, mounted on /home

I also tried to follow the steps described in the [official Ubuntu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html.en), to no avail. I can't find a "Create a new empty partition table on this device?" item in any menu available. As this is the second step of the described process, it's of no use.

Comment: Ok, I'm using Ubuntu Live Server, which is a different thing that Ubuntu Server, and seems to have problems with software RAID... I will try the real Ubuntu Server. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029854/raid-set-up-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Yeah, using the real Ubuntu Server, with Debian Installer, and not Ubuntu Live Server, with Live Installer, was the solution. I was up and running in 30 minutes. Live Server is a disaster...